# ActiveAdmin Inherited Ressource override doesn't work with multiple namespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I'm using ActiveAdmin with no default namespace (`config.default_namespace = false`). I have a `User` Resource without namespace as well as an `User` Resource in the `:admin` namespace. Both use custom update methods to achieve different behavior (users can change their own data, while admins can reset the password of any user).

This is the "default" user:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  actions :show, :edit, :update
  menu false
  permit_params ...

  controller do
    def update
      # change account data
      ...
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    ...
  end
end
```

And this is the admin User:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, namespace: :admin do
  actions :all
  menu
  permit_params ...

  controller do
    def create
      # invitation code
      ...
    end

    def update
      # password reset code
      ...
    end
  end

  index do
    ...
  end

  filter ...

  form partial: 'form'
end
```

Changing the user data works just fine, as well as inviting new users. The problem is the password reset. When submitting the corresponding form (route `/admin/users/[id]/edit`), the `update` of the non-namespaced users is called (same as when submitting `/users/[id]/edit`) instead of the update in my `:admin` namespace User resource.

Is this a bug or did I misconfigure something? I'm honestly stumped by this behavior, I don't even know how to proceed with debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't due to the namespaces, but because of my form...
I'm using `semantic_form_for`, which automatically configures everything based on the model. Since it receives an `User`, the form action will always send the data to the default `User` route instead of the `:admin` route. Manually setting the url fixed the problem.